# Может ли бот на aiogram проверять добавил ли человек новых пользователей в беседу, и какое количество?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram

Читал документацию aiogram, но не нашел. Может кто знает, с помощью какого метода - бот может отследить добавление новых участников от конкретного человека, и количество приглашенных участников от этого человека?

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS)
async def check_new_user(message: types.Message):

    invited_user = message.new_chat_members[0].full_name        # Кого пригласили в группу
    who_invited = message.from_user.full_name                   # Кто пригласил

    for user in message.new_chat_members:
        print(user.full_name)

    print(f'{invited_user=} - {who_invited=}')
```